# Is there a way to animate appearing text in html/css?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to animate slowly appearing text in css and I can't make it fluid... It consists of 3 words and will smoothly do the first word, but the next 2 words just pop into existence.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Not really my first website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="header">Marginalized Speeding Tickets</h1>
    <div class="newclass"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

````
.header{
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  position: top;
  left: 40%;
  border-bottom: 5px solid greenyellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: animate 2s linear forwards;
}
.header h1 {
  color: green;
}
@keyframes animate {
  0% { 
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    width: 50px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 50px;
    height: 80px;
  }
}```
````

Comment: It's ok for you to use jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for height in the keyframe, the problem is that the h1 is a block element and it breaks the words because of width 0px, but if you put in a `white-space: nowrap;` it should be fine, also `position: top;` is not valid, not sure what your trying there.
PS i you want he h1 to be green, first the element then the class selector `h1.header {color: green;}`

```css
.header {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 5px solid greenyellow;
  animation: animate 2s linear forwards;
}
h1.header {
  color: green;
}
@keyframes animate {
  0% { 
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="header">Marginalized Speeding Tickets</h1>
<div class="newclass"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed the issue and helped me out a lot. Also just a quick side question if you have the time, if you don't, no need to respond. Is it possible to make this animation repeat itself in x amount of seconds?

Comment: No problem, with pure css only if you do something like this: animation: animate 2s linear forwards, animate 2s linear forwards 5s; (in one line). So, if you repeat the same animation but with a delay, the last 5s represents animation-delay (you can change it to different number but not less than 2s because the animation itself needs 2s to complete). Technically this is cheating  but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your means correctly It's because you have use 50px width in your key frame and it can only appear first word you can change that